# combine two indexOf and regex into one using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have tried combining these two conditions into one, but the results were not what I wanted.

```
    var name = 'Ron & Peggy Sue'; //or 'Ron and Peggy Sue';

    if ( name.indexOf('&') > -1 ){
        names = name.split(/ & /g);
    }

    if ( name.toLowerCase().indexOf(' and ') > -1 ) {
        names = name.split(/ and /gi);
    }
```

Its supposed to return an array of names like:

```
names = ['Ron', 'Peggy Sue']; //regardless of `&` or `and` separator
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
name.split(/\s+(?:and|&)\s+/i)
```

Example:

```
var tests = [
  'Ron & Peggy Sue and Reandy',
  'Ron and Peggy Sue',
]

tests.map(function(x){return x.split(/\s+(?:and|&)\s+/i)})
//^
//[ [ 'Ron', 'Peggy Sue', 'Reandy' ], [ 'Ron', 'Peggy Sue' ] ]
```

Comment: `var names = 'randy';`

Comment: thanks. i was using `(&|and)` and it was being captured.

Comment: `\s` works on end of string too, is there a way to force whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

Try to combine two regex

```
 names = name.split(/\s&\s|\sand\s/ig);
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ax5fu/

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNames (str) {
    return str.split(/ & | and /gi);
}
```

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/db2sH/

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = 'Ron & Peggy Sue'; //or 'Ron and Peggy Sue';

if (name.indexOf('&') > -1 || name.toLowerCase().indexOf(' and ') > -1) {
    names = name.replace(/ and /gi, ' & ').split(/ & /g);
}

console.log(names);
```